# Proof of unique device

Tags: spam

Does Android offer ways to sign a proof of a unique hardware device?

- It can be a cryptographic proof; it does not need to be fixed id, so it can be used for tracking
- This would be mainly used to combat spam/bots
- The assumption is that if we can have proof of real hardware devices, any spammer does not have access to a significant number of hardware devices (thousands)
- The proof would not be used to track users
- The proof would need to be generated and checked only once per user

Are there other alternatives for such proofs in Android/Google ecosystem?

Comment: I'm assuming you know about: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids#best-practices-android-identifiers and specifically the section on "Avoid using hardware identifiers"

Comment: What is different is that I am asking for proof of uniqueness, not a hardware identifier. It does not need to be a static id.

Comment: But thanks to your comment, I read your link again and I think this is what could fill my use case https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/attestation - but it still lacks the aspect of whether the device is unique or not (e.g. no double attention o the same device)